# DataJPATest Junit method naming and NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I'm using SpringBoot/Kotlin/JPA/Hibernate/Junit and have JpaServiceTest class that exercises the repository methods pertaining to a single Entity. The method names of JpaService Class follow the convention `findByXXXXId`, `findAll`, `updateXXXX`, `addXXXX` and `deleteXXXX`.

To maintain consistency I named the methods in the JpaTest Class using the same convention. My JpaTest Class has two findById scenarios, one where the 'Null' is expected an another where the mapped entity is returned. My application works as expected however my test class fails on the findById scenario that is expected to return a valid Entity.

```
The service class

@Service("MyService")
@Transactional
internal class JpaMyService(val MyRepo: MyRepository) : MyService {

val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MyService")

override fun findByMyId(MyId: Long): MyDto? {
    log.debug("Retrieving My: {}", MyId)
    return MyRepo.findOne(MyId)?.toDto()
}

override fun findAllMys(): List<MyDto> {
    log.debug("Retrieving Mys")
    return MyRepo.findAll().map { it.toDto() }
}

override fun updateMy(id: Long?, My: UpdateMyDto): MyDto? {
    log.debug("Updating My: {} with data: {}", id, My)
    val currentMy = MyRepo.findOne(id)
    return if (currentMy != null) MyRepo.save(MyEntity.fromDto(My, currentMy)).toDto()
    else null
}

override fun addMy(My: CreateMyDto): MyDto {
    log.debug("Adding My: {}", My)
    return MyRepo.save(MyEntity.fromDto(My)).toDto()
}

override fun deleteMy(id: Long?) {
    log.debug("Deleting My: {}", id)
    MyRepo.delete(id)
}
```

The offending method

```
@Test
fun `'findMyById' should map existing entity from repository`() {
    repository.save(MyEntity(1, "name", "description"))
    val result = service.findByMyId(1)
    softly.assertThat(result?.id).isEqualTo(1)
    softly.assertThat(result?.name).isEqualTo("name")
    softly.assertThat(result?.description).isEqualTo("description")
}

Test failure

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :"name"
Actual   :null
```

Changing the name of the failing `findByMyId` method to either `getByMyId` or `retrieveByMyId` allows the test case to pass successfully from both command line and IDE. The test would always work from the IDE if run as a single test, irrespective of the name, but when the test class is run as a whole it would fail.

I'd like to know what the problem is with using findByXXId to return and Entity and this works when I change the name of the test method to start with either get or retrieve. If I use any other method name it also fails and what is more, even when I change the method name in other Services and Test classes I'm seeing a failure, due to a NPE.

Apologies in advance if this doesn't make sense, but I'm new to this stack and its taken three days to identify why these tests fail when the application works perfectly well.

Comment: Sounds like your test depends on other tests and the name changing affects the order of tests. Try adding a repository.flush after repository.save and annotating the test with @Transactional

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions but the problem persists. If I name the test method findByXXXXId it fails, but if I keep the implementation exactly the same and but rename it to either getByXXXXId or retrieveByXXXXId the test passes successfully when the whole test class is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my first suggestions in the comments didn't seem to fix it here is a list of things to do in order to isolate the problem.

First just to make sure I've got the facts straight:

- Your test works in the IDE
- Your test fails when run with all the other tests (presumably using Maven or similar)
- Your test works when run with all the other tests, but renamed.

My hunch from the comments still holds: This is not directly related to the name but to interdependencies between tests.

1. Create a minimal scenario that reproduces the problem in the IDE.

   a) run all the tests in the IDE (should be possible by selecting the test sources folder and selecting "Run tests" or something.

   b) assuming the test fails reduce the test scope by selecting smaller and smaller parts of the tree.

   c) if the test doesn't fail at all in the IDE you can do the same using include/exclude in Maven or any other respectable build tool.

   d) another variation of this is to create a dedicated TestSuite including all the tests.

   In general, by removing about half the tests in each step you should be able to end up with a test suite of two test in reasonable time: the problematic test and one more test triggering the first one to fail.
2. Activate logging for SQL and Transaction handling.

   You should see a rollback after the first test. Followed by the inserts of the second test. You should not see any commit.

   If you don't see the rollback your test is either not annotated with `@Transactional` or the transaction isn't picked up for some reason.

   If you don't see the inserts, your changes seem not to get flushed.
3. Using the JDBC template issue select statements to see the content of your database. Use trivial statements like `select * from x`. No where clause, no join. Log the results.

Chances are with this information the problem became obvious for you. If not update the question and comment on this answer. I'll take another look.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: Your initial hunch was correct, I traced the problem back to the order of Junit tests not being predictable and ID's utilising GenerationType.AUTO. The transactions are rolling back after every test however the ID being used to save every new entity increases and is thus not predictable. I'm going to alter the test case to utilise @BeforeAll to set up the test data rather than doing it within each test. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Also, changing the method names worked, sometimes, because it would change the order of the findBy method so that it would indeed find an entity with id of 1. It would become the first method to run and store an entity.